# How to get string follow url use javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a url

```
http://localhost:8162/UI/UsersDetail.aspx?id_temp=U0001
```

I want to get string use javascript

```
?id_temp=U0001
```

Thank guys.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter

Comment: Atleast do some google..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Do you both realize the links you give don't answer this question (which is probably a  duplicate) ?

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't the location of the page, you may use

```
var str = url.match(/\?.*$/)[0];
```

If this url is the current one of your page, use

```
var str = location.search;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex`:

```
url.match(/\?(\w+=\w+)/)[0];
```

1. `/` : Delimiter of `regex`
2. `\?` : Matches `?` need to escape using `\`
3. `\w+`: Matches all alphanumeric characters and `_`
4. `=` : Matches `=`